# How to run functions on main thread without using Coroutine in Unity

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, mono

I've come across some articles about using coroutine to run functions on main thread, such as [Thread Ninja](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15717):

```
 IEnumerator StartExamples()
{
    //Jump to main thread
    yield return Ninja.JumpToUnity; 

    Destroy(someGameObject); //OK

    //Jump back to background thread
    yield return Ninja.JumpBack;  
}
```

It didn't work on my code since I wanted to jump to main thread from a socket listener.

```
 SocketIOClient.Client socket;

 IEnumerator StartExamples()
 {
    socket.On("connect", (fn) =>
    {
        WriteLine("\r\nConnected event...\r\n");

        //Jump to main thread
        yield return Ninja.JumpToUnity; //ERROR: couldn't do a yield return 

        Destroy(someGameObject); 

        //Jump back to background thread
        yield return Ninja.JumpBack;  //ERROR: couldn't do a yield return 
    });
 }
```

So do we have any workaround for this? I wish I could jump to main thread like this:

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    //Unity API
    Destroy(gameObject);
});
```

Comment: The second parameter of socket.On( is a function, there You can't use yield.

Maybe you can use flag and start a coroutine like StartExample and wait for the connection with something like:  "while(flagNotReady) { yield return null; }"

Comment: that's my problem. I don't want to use coroutines because I'm gonna have lots of listeners in my code. Flags and coroutines will make my code becomes unclean and hard to be maintained.

Comment: Have you considered using something like Promises?

Comment: @AtraViator I've just googled it, seems like it's more about callbacks handling or executing functions sequentially, great extension btw. But I'm struggling with how to jump to UI thread from current thread (my code above, socket.On listener was running on a background thread), because Unity APIs only run on mainthread.

Comment: @FlySoFast In a previous project of mine, we used uPromise. By resolving the promise inside your background thread socket connect action, and providing the actual code to execute inside the .Done() of a promise (Which is declared on the main thread), you can then run code on the UI thread. It's not quite the same as 'jumping thread' inside the same code block, but it can provide a maintainable codebase and did for my project. If you're interested I can provide a real answer below with code example.

Comment: @AtraViator hey that's a great workaround, way better than using flags! By the way I've just found an awesome library comes with full source code, solved my problem exactly in the way I wanted. It also provides a lot more useful function about threading in Unity! You may want to take a look at it. I posted the link in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a very helpful extension called [Unity Thread Helper](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-threading-helper.90128/). It's free, and more than enough for my need!

This is the usage:

```
 UnityThreadHelper.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
        {
            Destroy(a);

        });
```

NOTICE: Dispatcher is a singleton object, it will be initialized on your first call. You have to do your first call on main thread, because it uses some Unity API.

```
 private void Start()
{
    var ugly = UnityThreadHelper.Dispatcher;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @seaders please provide your own answer since you have a different function call.

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment, using [uPromise](http://stephenlautier.blogspot.tw/p/upromise.html);

```
class Example
{
    private Promise BeginSocketConnection()
    {
        Deferred retPromise = new Deferred();

        socket.On("connect", (fn) =>
        {
            // We're no longer on the main thread ):
            // But we can resolve our promise!
            retPromise.Resolve();
        });

        return retPromise;
    }

    private void SocketConnectedSuccessfully()
    {
       // Executing on main thread
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // We start in the main thread
        BeginSocketConnection().Done(x =>
        {
            SocketConnectedSuccessfully();
        });
    }
}
```

This doesn't allow you to jump between threads within the same codeblock, but by using a callback system you can alert the main thread to execute an action without messy coroutines being started and yielded all over the place. Much nicer to look at and maintain.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use extensions, like uPromise and Unity Thread Helper mentioned in the other comments, and don't want to use MonoBehavior's coroutines, you can also use [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=net-5.0):

```
// On main thread, during initialization:
var syncContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;

// On socket listener thread
syncContext.Post(_ =>
{
    // This code here will run on the main thread
    Destroy(gameObject);
}, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer seems to be not documented on the site, here is my working solution (not thoroughly tested).

```
Dispatcher.Enqueue(() =>
{
    // Unity API
    Destroy(gameObject);
});
```